# Static import statements which should never be after nonstatic imports

Tags: java, groovy, static, import, codenarc

Codenarc is a framework that analyzes Groovy code for defects, bad practices, inconsistencies, style issues and more.

Is there a reason for this rule: **[MisorderedStaticImports Rule](http://codenarc.sourceforge.net/codenarc-rules-imports.html#MisorderedStaticImports)**:

> Checks for static import statements which should
>   never be after nonstatic imports.
>
> Examples of violations:
>
> ```
> import my.something.*
> import static foo.bar.*
>
> public class MyClass{}
> ```

I don't understand the motivation or implications for this rule.

Comment: It's convention only. As far as Java is concerned, it is irrelevant.

Comment: IntelliJ's formatter places static imports after normal imports by default.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah Idea does and it makes sense! look at the [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440653/why-do-i-get-different-compilation-result-depending-on-import-sequence-order)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Marko Topolnik says, the order of the imports is not relevant to the meaning of a program.

<sup>I tried looking at the JLS for an explicit statement to that effect, but I couldn't find one.  And the Java Tutorial doesn't mention import order either. However, the semantics of `import` are such that it makes no difference.  If the imports result in any potential ambiguity due to import order, the JLS says it is a compilation error.</sup>

Therefore, this is just a stylistic convention.  (Indeed, if you look at the rule, it even gives you the option of putting the static imports first!)

---

**UPDATE**

@Eugene Stepanenkov points out this Q&A

- [Why do I get different compilation result depending on java imports and static imports sequence order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440653/why-do-i-get-different-compilation-result-depending-on-import-sequence-order)

That was caused by an obscure bug in versions of the Oracle Java compiler prior to Java 8.  It was (eventually) acknowledged as a bug and fixed.

I guess, that means that the bug *could* have been part of the motivation for the Codenarc warning.  However if you were using a Java compiler affected by the bug, then any code with the imports in the "wrong" order would not compile at all ... rendering the Codenarc warning moot.

Answer (score 1):

Choosing the order of imports (static and non-static) may produce a problem in a such edge case as in [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40440653/why-do-i-get-different-compilation-result-depending-on-import-sequence-order).

Answer (score 0):

A style issue. There will be just one, two static imports, but which have a great impact on the understandability like introducing function names. Hence placing them at the top (for reading) might be considered good style. The IDE collapsing "[+]" support might have been taken in consideration too.

I think they wanted the static imports to be separated from the other ones.